# Q: Ngrok configure file not found

Tags: apache, http, networking, tunnel, ngrok

I want to open 2 ports by ngrok. first I started ngrok HTTP 80 worked ok. but when I try to open another ngrok TCP 443 the result 
Tunnel session failed:

> Your account 'USERNAME' is limited to 1 simultaneous ngrok client
>   session. Active ngrok client sessions in region 'us':
>     - 806d84d5e153ff13136eddee04de8157 (x.x.x.x)
>
> ERR_NGROK_108

I found one solution but I don't know to configure ngrok.yml for the tunnel .
I couldn't find the file ...help me please

Answer (score 2):

In GUI Files:

1. Open Home Folder
2. Press Ctl + H
3. In search box type "ngrok"
4. directory will apear in first place
5. double click on .ngrok2

In Ternminal:

1. cd home
2. cd user
3. ls -a
4. cd .ngrok2
5. emacs ngrok.yml

Answer (score 1):

It would help to confirm that you have created an account first. Once you have an account you would be given an authtoken running this command

```
./ngrok authtoken <your-auth-toke>
```

or

```
ngrok authtoken <your-auth-toke>
```

would create both the .ngrock2 folder and the config file.

This is what worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

> An ngrok account is limited in how many agents it can simultaneously run. This limit is listed for each plan as "online ngrok processes" on the pricing page. This error indicates you've exceeded that limit.
>
> https://ngrok.com/docs/errors/err_ngrok_108

You may need to upgrade your plan, or email `support@ngrok.com`.

---

I had a simmilar problem, and:

```
ngrok config upgrade
```

Worked for me